# Wordpress custom post type term archive pages redirection issue after custom rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I created a custom post type called "Ad" and a taxonomy called "Ad Category". The term pages need a custom display, not the default theme archive display.

In order to solve this, I have created a regular page "Ad Archive" and added the desired display there. Then I set a rewrite rule for the term pages, so they display what's on the "Ad Archive" page, like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '^ad-archive[\/(.*)]*\/?', 'index.php?page_id=AD-ARCHIVE-PAGE-ID', 'top' );
```

It is working like a charm, the custom post type term archive pages are displaying what's in the "Ad Archive" page.

**HOWEVER**, the issue is that when setting the "Ad Archive" page as the home page, all the term archive pages also redirect to the home page.

Is there a way to stop this redirection when setting the "Ad Archive" page as the home?

Any other way to accomplish this?